# Fetch href Value from HTML File via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fetch

I have this Problem.

I am using Grid.js (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/)

And now I want to add a Lightbox with multiple thumbnails inside the dropout.

Grid.js has an function where it puts all the content into the dropout, so I thought I may use this function.

```
this.$href = $('<div class="image-row"><div class="image-set"><a class="example-image-link" href="img/demopage/image-3.jpg" data-lightbox="example-set" title="Click on the right side of the image to move forward."></div>');
```

I shortenend the code, its very long (not very pretty I admitt), now it shows on the dropout, but I need for each Dropout a new set of images.

Is there any way I can fetch the href="" data out of the HTML? Or another, more practical way to do it?

I admit I have absolutly no clue of JavaScript.... I hope someone can help me! Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you tried `var link=$('#yourElementsId').attr('href')`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use `$('.example-image-link').attr('href');`

Comment: But the .example-image-link has to be set to one class or doesn't it? Because I need it to be very flexible

Comment: @user2891014 if you can't rely on this class, use something else. like `$('.image-set a').attr('href')`

Comment: You can use $('a').attr('href'); to get the href of link elements... or $('.image-set a').attr('href'); to get the href of links nested within that parent class div. It just depends on how you need to arrive at the selector...

Comment: Very stupid question...but where do I put this? I tried putting it into the function, but after that the site isn't responding at all!

Comment: Not a stupid question, but difficult to help with without greater context about your script.